# Get result before end of function node

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I can't reach my value until my function is ending.. I tried callbacks but it seems to doesn't work..

```
exports.helloHttp = function helloHttp (req, res) {
    var url = "https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json";
    var btcValue
    require('https').get(url, function(res, btcValue){
        var body = '';

        res.on('data', function(chunk){
            body += chunk;
         });

        res.on('end', function(){
            btcValue = JSON.parse(body);
            callback(btcValue);
        });
        }).on('error', function(e){
          console.log("Got an error: ", e);
        });
     console.log("Got a respons ", btcValue);
     res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 
     res.send(JSON.stringify({ "speech": response, "displayText": response 
    }));
};
```

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Where is `callback` here?? you just callled callback but  where it is?? The above code should throw error `callback is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

I've written a standalone example based on your code:

```
var http = require('http'),
    https = require('https');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    // You can largely ignore the code above this line, it's
    // effectively the same as yours but changed to a standalone
    // example. The important thing is we're in a function with
    // arguments called req and res.
    var url = 'https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json';

    var request = https.get(url, function(response) {
        var body = '';

        response.on('data', function(chunk) {
            body += chunk;
        });

        response.on('end', function() {
            // TODO: handle JSON parsing errors
            var btcValue = JSON.parse(body);

            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

            res.end(JSON.stringify({
                btcValue: btcValue
            }));
        });
    });

    request.on('error', function(e) {
        console.error(e);
    });

    // Runs this example on port 8000
}).listen(8000);
```

The most important change is moving the code for handling our response (`res`) into the `'end'` listener of the coindesk response. That call to coindesk is asynchronous so we have to wait for the `'end'` event before we try to act on it.

You reference a variable called `response` twice when building your JSON. Your code didn't define `response` but I've assumed that it is supposed to be related to the `btcValue` coming back from the call to coindesk. I wasn't sure exactly what you wanted there so I've just wrapped `btcValue` in another object for demonstration purposes.

In your original code you had this line:

```
require('https').get(url, function(res, btcValue){
```

That second argument, which you've called `btcValue`, doesn't exist so it will just be set to `undefined`.

I've changed `send` to `end` but that isn't a significant change. I assume you're using Express (which provides a `send` method) whereas my example is not.